# In `array` environment, why does `\multirow` stretch rows too much when using `=` for width entry?

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices, multirow, arrays

When `=` is used, the content of `\multirow` command is adjusted to automatically be equal to the column in which `\multirow` appears. But this does not seem to be the case with me. I am trying to use `array` environment to build detailed matrices with columns and rows separators for illustration purposes. I get the following output

[image]

I got the output by adjusting the width of `\multirow` manually. If I adjust it to be `=`, the output stretches beyond margins

[image]

My source code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}
\setlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}{2.12mm}
\newcommand{\arraycolsepdefault}{ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{\arraycolsepdefaultl} }
\arraycolsepdefault

\newcommand {\arraystretchdefaultl} {1.3}
\newcommand{\arraystretchdefault}{ \renewcommand {\arraystretch} {\arraystretchdefaultl} }
\arraystretchdefault


\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.06mm}
\left[
    \begin{array}{c}
        V_{1}
        \\
        \vdots
        \\
        V_{k}
        \\
        \vdots
        \\
        V_{p}
        \\
        \vdots
        \\ \Xhline{0.25mm}
        0
    \end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\left[
    \begin{array}{c >{\medspace}c !{\vrule width 0.25mm}>{\medspace}c}
        \multirow{5}{=}{\centering \LARGE $\bm{Z}_{orig}$} & &  \multirow{5}{=}{\centering $col. \thinspace k - col. \thinspace p$} 
        \\
        & &
        \\
        & &
        \\
        & &
        \\
        & &
        \\
        \Xhline{0.25mm}
        row. \thinspace k - row. \thinspace p & & Z_{th, \thinspace kp} + Z_{b}
    \end{array}
\right]
\arraystretchdefault
\left[
    \begin{array}{c}
        I_{1}
        \\
        \vdots
        \\
        I_{k}
        \\
        \vdots
        \\
        I_{p}
        \\
        \vdots
        \\
        \Xhline{0.25mm}
        I_{q}
    \end{array}
\right]
\arraycolsepdefault
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are changing `\arraystretch` in the middle of your set of `array` constructions, and that affects how the number of rows for `\multirow{<rows>}` is interpreted. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: No, I am changing it before array environment is initiated. I change the array stretch so that elements are vertically separated and become more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example avoids [`multirow`](//ctan.org/pkg/multirow) but instead uses `\vphantom`s to ensure that the matrix constructs match each other (vertically). The centred element is raise 1/2 a baseline to put it in the middle of the line (since there are an even number of rows above the `\Xhline`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm,makecell,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \left[\begin{array}{ c }
    V_1    \\
    \vdots \\
    V_k    \\
    \vdots \\
    V_p    \\
    \vdots \\
    \Xhline{0.25mm}
    0
  \end{array}\right]
  =
  \left[\begin{array}{ c !{\vrule width 0.25mm} c }
    \vphantom{V_1} & \\
    \vphantom{\vdots} & \\
    \vphantom{V_k} & \\
    \vphantom{\vdots}\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$\bm{Z}_{\text{orig}}$} & 
      \raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\text{col.\ k - col.\ p}} \\
    \vphantom{V_p} & \\
    \vphantom{\vdots} \\
    \Xhline{0.25mm}
    \text{row.\ k - row.\ p} & Z_{\text{th, kp}} + Z_b
  \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{ c }
      I_1    \\
      \vdots \\
      I_k    \\
      \vdots \\
      I_p    \\
      \vdots \\
      \Xhline{0.25mm}
      I_q
  \end{array}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a desired result since the column widths are determined automatically depending on the contents. The use of `\vphantom` over and over again seems to be redundant. I wonder if someone can create a package to automatically force brackets surrounding `array` environment equal

Comment: You can use `bmatrix` from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). The horizontal spacing will have to be adjusted.

Comment: will `bmatrix` provide the ability to customize the matrix similarly to what we get with `array` environment?

Comment: `bmatrix` will provide the ability to bracket a matrix without the column specifications.

Answer (score 1):

- `\multirow{5}{=}{...}` consider used column width
- since in your case it is not defined in advance (as at columns as are `p{<width>}`), it for it consider `\linewidth`, consequently result which you obtained
- a cure: use `\multirow{5}{*}{...}` instead:

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}

  \usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage{multirow}

  \newlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}
  \setlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}{2.12mm}
  \newcommand{\arraycolsepdefault}{ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{\arraycolsepdefaultl} }
  \arraycolsepdefault

  \newcommand {\arraystretchdefaultl} {1.3}
  \newcommand{\arraystretchdefault}{ \renewcommand {\arraystretch} {\arraystretchdefaultl} }

  \usepackage{bm}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{equation}
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.06mm}
  \arraystretchdefault
  \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
          V_{1}   \\
          \vdots  \\
          V_{k}   \\
          \vdots  \\
          V_{p}   \\
          \vdots  \\
      \Xhline{0.25mm}
          0\rule{0pt}{3.5ex}
      \end{array}
  \right]
  =
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
  \left[
      \begin{array}{c >{\medspace}c !{\vrule width 0.25mm}>{\medspace}c}
          \multirow{5}{*}{\centering \LARGE $\bm{Z}_{orig}$}
              &   &   \multirow{5}{*}{$\text{col. } k - \text{col. } p$} \\
              &   &   \\
              &   &   \\
              &   &   \\
              &   &   \\
          \Xhline{0.25mm}
          $\text{col. } k - \text{col. } p$
              &   &   Z_{th,\, kp} + Z_{b}
      \end{array}
  \right]
  \arraystretchdefault
  \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
          I_{1}   \\
          \vdots  \\
          I_{k}   \\
          \vdots  \\
          I_{p}   \\
          \vdots  \\
          \Xhline{0.25mm}
          I_{q}\rule{0pt}{3.5ex}
      \end{array}
  \right]
      \end{equation}
  \end{document}
  ```

which fives:

[image]

however, approach showed in [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) answer is common in similar cases.